# for loop iterations in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm building a simple list using a dynamically allocated array in C++. I have a function `remove(int item)` that should remove all occurrences of `item` in the list. However, if I make a loop that iterates from `0` to `length` in the array, I'm worried I will exceed the boundaries of my array because `length` changes as I delete items:

```
int List::pop(int index)
{
  int retval = data[index];
  for (int i = index; i < length; i++)
    data[i] = data[i+1];
  length--;
  return retval;
}

void List::remove(int item)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (data[i] == item)
      pop(i);
}
```

So, if I called `remove(6)` on `array[6][4][2][6][1][3][5][6]`, would C++ update the `for` loop in `remove()` with the updated value of `length` after a `pop()`? Or would it remain the same value that was originally passed to it when `remove()` was called?

Comment: So I guess in simpler terms, is C++ call-by-value or call-by-reference in this case?

Comment: This algorithm has O(N^2) performance, as `pop()` copies the rest of the values one step at a time even if there are multiple copies of the item.  You can easily get a single pass O(N) solution by keeping the index of the "packed" data and copying `!= item` elements directly there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution would be to search the reverse. Only keep those which are not equal to the item to be removed.

```
void List::remove(int item)
{
    int insert = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (data[i] != item)
          data[insert++] = data[i];
    }
    length = insert;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the only approach that doesn't do any wasted work. Nothing is moved more than once. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Start at the end of the array and work backwards to the start position. Alternatively, call `pop(i--)` instead of `pop(i)`. This backs up `i` so you don't skip any elements of the list (including the last item).

The advantage of the first method is that you don't waste time shifting down elements that are eventually going to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional expression `i < length` is evaluated in it's entirety before every iteration of the loop.  The C++ compiler will not cache `i` nor will it cache `length` for this evaluation.  So long as the `length` variable is properly updated this expression won't allow `i` to be beyond the bounds of the array.

This won't help with the skipping elements problem though.  To do that I would switch to a while loop.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < length) {
  if (data[i] == item) {
    pop(i);
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

In this case we don't increment if we `pop` an item.  This way the index remains in the same place and will be able to catch duplicate items which appear next to each other in the array

Comment: His problem isn't really going past the end of the list; it's skipping each element that follows any removed element.

Comment: +1 While loop is also preferable to for loop here, because it clues the reader that the number of iterations is not fixed at the start of the loop. That is not nearly as obvious when written as a for loop.